# ModelAndView, a parameter returned by the interceptor postHandle, is null

Tags: spring-boot

I know that PostHandle works after Controller's logic is completed.
However, in the current state, the controller returns modelAnView and redirects it to the corresponding page. However, when there is no image corresponding to the src value of the img tag on this page, and a 404 error occurs in the browser, the ModelAndView of postHandle becomes null. No matter how hard I try, I can't find the cause. please help
Below is my code.
ps>If not 404, modelAndView is not null

-- Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/before"})  //PostMapping
public ModelAndView beforePayment(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        ModelAndView mav,
        @RequestBody MultiValueMap map,
        @RequestAttribute(required = false) LoginDetail loginDetail) {
    ...
    ...
    mav.addObject("data", data);
    log.info("data  >> {}" , data);
    mav.setViewName( "pay/before_payment" );
    return mav;
```

-- before_payment.jsp

```
...
...
<span class="orderItemTable__item__thumb"><img src="<c:out value='${order_info.goods_info.image_path}' default='img/temp/pdt_thumb1.png' />" alt=''></span>
// img default src 404
```

-- Interceptor

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
// ModelAndView is null
```